# Gradle sync failed: Cause: error=0, spawn failed

Tags: android, github

Cannot build android project from Github the error is 
"   Gradle sync failed: Cause: error=0, spawn failed
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (434ms)

any ideas ?

Comment: post your gradle files !!

Comment: execute gradlew command like "gradlew --info --stacktrace" and see if you have errors

Answer (score 10):

try to restart android studio, it worked for me. Gradle back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

To restart Android Studio sometimes does **not** **enough**. You should close it and restart your computer. After that you can open Android Studio without error.

Answer (score 0):

This error may cause due to changing of packages and code, I had a same problem, try Debugging your code first instead of directly jumps to running, its worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Reinstall your IDE. This happened to me because I accidentally deleted the IDE, so I had to reinstall it.